# Variable not available in alternative template

Tags: theming, 8

I'd like to override the `field--image.html.twig` template from my base theme in my sub-theme. As I want to override it only for a specific field for a specific node type, I've created the template `field--node--field-pictures--slideshow.html.twig`.

The rare thing now is, that within the `field--image.html.twig` the variable `item.caption.title` (`item` is the iterator of `items`) is available, while in my alternative it is not (always `NULL`). Why is that so?